# Azure Table Query - Multiple Conditions On SubClassed Properties

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

**Summary**

- I am trying to query my azure table storage using multiple conditions.
- My entity object contains other subclasses, whose properties I want to query, as well as the partition key.
- Based on the below data model, a high level pseudo code version of my query would be:
- SELECT all MyEventEntity objects WHERE "partitionkey=SOMEVALUE" OR "Owner.ID=SOMEVALUE" OR "Guests.IDs.ToList().CONTAINS=SOMEVALUE".

**My Entity Data Model**

```
 public class MyEventEntity : TableEntity
        {
            public Owner Owner { get; set; }
            public List<Guest> Guests { get; set; }

            public MyEventEntity(string partitionKey, string rowKey)
            {
                this.PartitionKey = partitionKey;
                this.RowKey = rowKey;
                this.Guests = new List<Guest>();
            }
        }//End of class.

        public class Guest
        {
            public string ID { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string Surname { get; set; }

            public Guest()
            {

            }

        }//End of class.

        public class Owner
        {
            public string ID { get; private set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string Surname { get; set; }

            public Owner()
            {

            }
        }//End of class.
```

**Questions**

1. How do I go about implementing a query condition like this with multiple filters?
2. I presume I will need to use the TableQuery.CombineFilters function?
3. How do I actually access a property that is subclassed using this query method?

**UPDATE**

- Following lots of reading, I've compiled THREE potential answers, although am not able to execute them in code yet, so they might not work.
- I'd appreciate any comments in the meantime, either indicating if there's an issue with the syntax, or suggestions for potential performance improvements etc.

  ```
     var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
             var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
              //var table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
              //table.CreateIfNotExists();
              var tableServiceContext = tableClient.GetDataServiceContext();
           IEnumerable<MyEventEntity> query = from entity in
           tableServiceContext.CreateQuery<MyEventEntity>("myevententities")
                  where entity.PartitionKey.Equals("SomeValue")
                  || entity.Owner.ID.Equals("SomeValue")
                  || entity.Guests.Where(ID => ID == "SomeValue")
                  select entity;
          //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

          var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
          var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
          //var table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
          //table.CreateIfNotExists();
          var tableServiceContext = tableClient.GetDataServiceContext();

           var query = (from entity in tableServiceContext.CreateQuery<MyEventEntity>("myevententities")
               where entity.PartitionKey.Equals("SomeValue")
                      || entity.Owner.ID.Equals("SomeValue")
                      || entity.Guests.Where(ID => ID == "SomeValue")
               select new MyEventEntity()).AsTableServiceQuery();

          return query.ToList<MyEventEntity>();

          //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

         var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
          var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
          //var table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
          //table.CreateIfNotExists();
          var tableServiceContext = tableClient.GetDataServiceContext();

          IEnumerable<MyEventEntity> query = 
              tableServiceContext.Where(pk => pk.PartitionKey.Equals("SomeValue") 
              || oID => oID.Owner.ID.Equals("SomeValue")
              || gID => gID.Guests.Where(ID => ID.Equals("SomeValue")).ToList();
  ```

**Update 2**

- I think I've just realised that table storage won't support my data model, regardless of the querying aspect......